# How to add a javascript inside of code?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    Response.Write("<script>setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(\"basic-modal\").style.display = 'block'}, 400)</script>");
}
```

Is there a better way to do that?
It works, but has an affect on css of certain elements.

Comment: "*It works, but has an affect on css of certain elements*" - that's not clear at all, nor is what you're looking for

Comment: I just wanted to tell you that  this type of code that combines backend and frontend together is really bad and old fashioned .Javascript in C# not recommended.

Comment: What would you guys recommend to do instead?

Comment: I've googled a little bit. 
I think 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479011.aspx can help you?

Comment: Try to use  `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(),"","Your script ",true)`  may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying my best to infer what you mean.

Is your issue that the `block` display is not correct, you want to show the element, but with its `initial` display value?

**If you want to restore the `initial` display of an element**, just 'empty' the display value `display=''`

*Note: This only removes `inline` style.  If you have otherwise styled this element in a stylesheet, that style will kick in.

With your example:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
{
    Response.Write("<script>setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById(\"basic-modal\").style.display = \"\"}, 400) </script>");
}
```